# How do I constrain my query in mongo, where I need a conditional join on the results

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a large collection of JSON  documents that has many entries of the following format (contents in my example are important to my question):

```
doc1
{
    "data": [{
            "entry": {
                "fieldA": "aaa",
                "fieldB": "xxx"
            }
        },
        {
            "entry": {
                "fieldA": "ccc",
                "fieldB": "yyy"
            }
        },
        {
            "entry": {
                "fieldA": "eee",
                "fieldB": "xxx"
            }
        }
    ]
}


doc2
{
    "data": [{
            "entry": {
                "fieldA": "aaa",
                "fieldB": "xxx"
            }
        },
        {
            "entry": {
                "fieldA": "ccc",
                "fieldB": "yyy"
            }
        },
        {
            "entry": {
                "fieldA": "eee",
                "fieldB": "nnn"
            }
        }
    ]
}
...

docN
{
    "data": [{
            "entry": {
                "fieldA": "aaa",
                "fieldB": "yyy"
            }
        },
        {
            "entry": {
                "fieldA": "ccc",
                "fieldB": "yyy"
            }
        },
        {
            "entry": {
                "fieldA": "eee",
                "fieldB": "xxx"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is create a query that follows the below rule:

Only returns documents where it has a `fieldA` that contains `aaa` and has another entry where `fieldA` contains `eee` AND where the `fieldB` of those entries have values that match.

In the above example, that would be the first top level document as the `fieldB` for both sub entries are `xxx`

Additionally it would be nice to have just the entries pruned in the returned document, instead of the whole document

Comment: Is the sample given supposed to represent three documents? If so, is each of the `entry` objects supposed to be a subdocument in an array? As written something seems incorrect as MongoDB doesn't formally support duplicate field names (nor does JSON)

Comment: Yes, these are 3 different documents.  Each entry is a sub document as well

Comment: I will fix my json and repost

Comment: @user20042973 I fixed my JSON... I'd appreciate any help with the query

Comment: Great. Is it safe to assume that each data array will have at most one `entry` where `fieldA` contains `aaa` and similarly for `eee`?

Comment: unable to understand your question clearly but you can use the @$elemMatch operator also you can prefer [mongodb nested array find examples](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/)

Comment: Unfortunately not, it can have more than one entries... but I will take what I can get, even if I find one.

Comment: give me some examples of expected output

Comment: For my example above, I would expect just the first document to be returned and not the other two.    And if the output can prune the uninteresting entry, that would be better.  So the ideal result would look as

`doc1
{
    "data": [{

            "entry": {

                "fieldA": "aaa",

                "fieldB": "xxx"
            }
        },
        {
            "entry": {
                "fieldA": "eee",
                "fieldB": "xxx"
            }
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: You'll want to use `$exp`r to access aggregation operators. Then you'll use `$let` to set `vars` that represent the two values and then compare them using `$eq` via the `in`. Will write it up tomorrow if nobody else does before then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option without unwinding and grouping again is:

1. Clean your data as requested.
2. `$match` only wanted documents

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      data: {$filter: {
          input: "$data",
          cond: {$or: [
              {$eq: ["$$this.entry.fieldA", "aaa"]},
              {$eq: ["$$this.entry.fieldA", "eee"]}
          ]}
      }}
  }},
  {$match: {
      $expr: {$and: [
          {$eq: [{$size: "$data"}, 2]},
          {$eq: [{$first: "$data.entry.fieldB"}, {$last: "$data.entry.fieldB"}]}
      ]}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uoOtLK06mEc)

Comment: Yeah logically this is along the lines of what I was thinking. My two extra comments are 1) there should probably be a `$match` at the beginning that does a direct comparison of the direct values for the `fieldA` entries (for index/performance reasons), and 2) I think OP wanted the full document back (not a filtered version)?

Comment: @user20042973. If I had to translate this to a Mongodb compass filter query, what would the same query look like?

Comment: I think you could only do this in the aggregation tab. If you wanted to use this logic in the other tab the 'workaround' would probably be to store this aggregation as a view in the database and point Compass toward that view. Are you looking to explore the matching data via the compass UI?

Answer (score 0):

**I hpoe this will return as you expected**

> https://mongoplayground.net/p/OcPAJ2FoQXi

```
[{
 $unwind: {
  path: '$data'
 }
}, {
 $match: {
  $or: [
   {
    'data.entry.fieldA': 'aaa'
   },
   {
    'data.entry.fieldA': 'eee'
   }
  ]
 }
}, {
 $group: {
  _id: '$_id',
  data: {
   $push: {
    fieldA: '$data.entry.fieldA',
    fieldB: '$data.entry.fieldB'
   }
  }
 }
}]
```

Comment: if you need the values inside the entry object you can do `entry : {     fieldA: '$data.entry.fieldA',    fieldB: '$data.entry.fieldB' }`  inside the @push operator